# How to sum dictionaries values with same key inside two list?

Tags: python

I have two list with dictionaries:

```
rich = [
    {'currency': 'USD', 'value': 100},
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 110},
    {'currency': 'USD', 'value': 120},
    {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 130},
]

poor = [
    {'currency': 'USD', 'value': 10},
    {'currency': 'AED', 'value': 20},
]
```

how can I combine both so that I can get:

```
rich_and_poor = [
    {'currency': 'USD', 'value': 110},  # +10
    {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 110},
    {'currency': 'GBP', 'value': 130},
    {'currency': 'AED', 'value': 20}  # new dictionary
]
```

?

The 
`from collections import Counter` is useful, because it can sum dictionaries values with same key, but I still can't figure out how to do it with list of dictionairies.

```
x = {'value': 123}
y = {'value': 2}

Counter(x) + Counter(y) = {'value': 125}
```

Comment: for item in list doesn't work ?

Comment: You have USD twice in rich is that correct?

Comment: Is it expected to have duplicated currencies in one single source list, as @Noelkd pointed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more logical structure for this would be to have one dictionary, with currencies as keys and values as values. Let's use a defaultdict to create one (so that new keys start out as 0 automatically):

```
currencies = defaultdict(int)
```

Now add your dicts to it:

```
for currencydict in rich + poor:
    currencies[currencydict['currency']] += currencydict['value']
```

That yielded something like (not necessarily the same order):

```
{
    'USD': 230,
    'EUR': 110,
    'GBP': 130,
    'AED': 20
}
```

And now, if you really have to, convert it back to a list like yours:

```
rich_and_poor = [{'currency': key, 'value': value} for key, value in currencies.items()]
```

Comment: wow I have this code in my text editor was just waiting for response to my question!

Comment: i did `map(lambda dp : {"currency" : dp[0], "value": dp[1]}, rich_and_poor.iteritems())` to put it back in the right shape

Comment: Yeah you asked a good question, I just went with the assumption that it was a mistake, if it's not then I think there's an XY problem anyway, because then the data looks even stranger.

Comment: I hear that, the thing that threw me was the expected output had both USD with in the list with only the first one getting the additional $10.